# To find the critical points of $f(x,y)=e^{-x}(x^{2}-5xy^{2}+4y^{4})$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am having hard time finding the critical points of **$$f(x,y)=e^{-x}(x^{2}-5xy^{2}+4y^{4})$$**, but i could not find. Can anyone help. Thanks

**EDIT**

When i substituted $x=\frac{16}{10}y^2$ in first equation i got a cubic mess. How i handle that?

Comment: Substitute $y^2=10x/16$ instead.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Look for the points $(a,b)$ where $f_x(a,b)=f_y(a,b)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

solve the system $$-e^{-x} \left(x^2-5 x y^2-2 x+4 y^4+5 y^2\right)=0$$
and $$e^{-x} \left(16 y^3-10 x y\right)=0$$
solving this system i got $$x=0,y=0$$, $$x=2,y=0$$, $$x=-2,y=-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$$, and $$x=2,y=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Comment: When i substituted $x=\frac{16}{10}y^2$ in first equation i got a cubic mess. How i handle that?

Comment: @TaylorTed. You do not get *a cubic mess*. Also do not forget that there is another solution for $f'_y=0$.